# Paypal check customer email before review

Tags: paypal, paypal-express

I have created a custom Magento module to check banned customers coming from Paypal and I overridden `returnfromPaypal` function:

```
    public function returnFromPaypal($token)
{
    $this->_getApi();
    $this->_api->setToken($token)->callGetExpressCheckoutDetails();

    // import billing address
    $billingAddress = $this->_quote->getBillingAddress();
    $exportedBillingAddress = $this->_api->getExportedShippingAddress();

        foreach ($exportedBillingAddress->getExportedKeys() as $key) {

            if (array_key_exists($key, $dataOrg))
            {                   
                $billingAddress->setData($key, $dataOrg[$key]);

            }
        }
        $this->_quote->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

    if( $this->isCustomerBanned( $this->_quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail() ) )
        {
             Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Sorry!, We cant process you order this time.'));
        }
        else
        {
            parent::returnFromPaypal($token);

        }

}
```

But the problem is when the `$billingAddress` is saved for the first time in the quote `$this->_quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail()` will be blank.

I want to know if there is another way to get customer email directly from `$exportedBillingAddress` I searched for documentation for it but nothing found. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How about using the customer email address set against the quote.

```
$this->_quote->getCustomerEmail()
```